# Render Selected button in whitespace using React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am facing the below problem in React -

So, I have a list of buttons at the bottom and when I select any button, the text should appear at the top in a given whitespace. Now I want to have the whitespace pre-occupied like shown in the image below -

[image]

Whenever a word is selected, the selected word should occupy that whitespace. In my current implementation, when a word is getting added, the list of words is pushed down because of the margin.

How can I have a whitespace that takes the selected words.

Many thanks

Comment: Just give fixed height to that particular row. I think that will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @divyesh makvana commented

Give fixed `height` to the particular `row`.

Comment: Yes, it is working now